# How to update a status message on the lotus connections server from the other web application?

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus, ibm-connections, atom-feed

I have found the following  [info](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ltscnnct/v2r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.connections.25.help/r_api_prof_update_board_status.html) "**To update a status message, send an updated status document in Atom format using an HTTP PUT request**"
but i don't  underctand how to sent the xml  file to the lotus connections server. I tried to  submit  a form with xml  data...I tried to call ajax query..

Please anybody help -  give me an example how I can  do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably grab some sample code from [this project](http://www.openntf.org/catalogs/a2cat.nsf/topicThread.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=34E023D2097639E88525768D0030FA6C) over at OpenNTF.org